# Ktor MalformedInputException when connecting to Python websockets

Tags: python, kotlin, websocket, ktor

I'm trying to organize websocket connection between python server and kotlin client. As websockets libraries I'm using websockets and ktor. I wrote two simple test applications. So when I try to get response text from server I get a MalformedInputException. Due to debug process I wrote simple websocket server using Node js and It works correct.
I suppose that I have problems with encoding but have no idea how to fix it.

Python Server

```
import asyncio
import websockets
from websockets import WebSocketServerProtocol

class Server:

    async def __respond(self, client: WebSocketServerProtocol, message: str):
        print(message)
        await client.send(message)

    async def ws_handler(self, client: WebSocketServerProtocol, uri: str) -> None:
        async for message in client:
            await self.__respond(client, message)

server = Server()
start_server = websockets.serve(server.ws_handler, '127.0.0.1', 4000)
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(start_server)
loop.run_forever()
```

Kotlin client

```
client.ws(
            method = HttpMethod.Get,
            host = "127.0.0.1",
            port = 4000,
            path = "/ws",
            request = {
                header("Sec-WebSocket-Extensions", "permessage-deflate")
            }
        ) {
            send(Frame.Text("message"))

            for (frame in incoming) {
                when (frame) {
                    is Frame.Text -> println(frame.readText())
                    is Frame.Binary -> println(String(frame.readBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
                    else -> println("error")
                }
            }
        }
```

Kotlin stacktrace

```
io.ktor.utils.io.charsets.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
    at io.ktor.utils.io.charsets.CharsetJVMKt.throwExceptionWrapped(CharsetJVM.kt:325)
    at io.ktor.utils.io.charsets.CharsetJVMKt.decode(CharsetJVM.kt:199)
    at io.ktor.utils.io.charsets.EncodingKt.decode(Encoding.kt:103)
    at io.ktor.utils.io.charsets.EncodingKt.decode$default(Encoding.kt:101)
    at io.ktor.http.cio.websocket.FrameCommonKt.readText(FrameCommon.kt:146)
    at com.veronica.service.Client$run$3.invokeSuspend(Client.kt:33)
```

Exception throws at "is Frame.Text -> println(frame.readText())" line

Ktor version is 1.6.0

Answer (score 0):

To make it work install [WebSocket Deflate extension](https://ktor.io/docs/websocket-deflate-extension.html):

```
HttpClient(CIO) {
    install(WebSockets) {
        extensions {
            install(WebSocketDeflateExtension) {
                compressionLevel = Deflater.DEFAULT_COMPRESSION
                compressIfBiggerThan(bytes = 4 * 1024)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and remove the code for setting the `Sec-WebSocket-Extensions` header:

```
request = {
    header("Sec-WebSocket-Extensions", "permessage-deflate")
}
```